# SQL-запрос для массового заполнения таблицы

Tags: sql, запрос

Приветствую, мне надо прописать одну картинку для товаров с id от 1 до 1261

Команда

```
INSERT INTO `catalogue_productimage` (`id`, `original`, `caption`, `display_order`, `date_created`, `product_id`)
VALUES (1, 'images/products/2016/09/none.png', '', 0, '2016-09-29 11:07:36', 1);
```

делает нужное для товара с id 1. Не в ручную же 1261 такой запрос создавать, подскажите, как автоматизировать.

Comment: Скопируйте запрос в Excel, разбейте по ячейкам и растяните его на 1261 строку.

Comment: можно хранимой процедурой в цикле составить запрос и гонять  с инкрементом.

Comment: А что мешает сделать `id` автоинкрементным полем?

Comment: Задача решается одним запросом с генерацией числовой последовательности:  http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_number_sequence_generation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предполагаю, что у вас есть некая таблица продуктов в которой уже существуют записи с такими id и вы хотите в связанную с ней таблицу изображений вставить указанные строки. Если так, то вы можете написать что то вроде:

```
INSERT INTO `catalogue_productimage` (`id`, `original`, `caption`, `display_order`,
                                      `date_created`, `product_id`)
select id, 'images/products/2016/09/none.png', '', 0, '2016-09-29 11:07:36', id
   from products
  where id between 1 and 1261
```

Если такой таблицы нет, то можно воспользоваться самой же таблицей `catalogue_productimage`. Для этого вставляем в нее вашу первую запись, а последующие вставляем несколькими запросами вроде таких (если в таблице изначально только 1 запись):

```
INSERT INTO `catalogue_productimage` (`id`, `original`, `caption`, `display_order`,
                                      `date_created`, `product_id`)
select id+1, original, caption, display_order, date_created, id+1
  from catalogue_productimage;

INSERT INTO `catalogue_productimage` (`id`, `original`, `caption`, `display_order`,
                                      `date_created`, `product_id`)
select id+2, original, caption, display_order, date_created, id+2
  from catalogue_productimage;

INSERT INTO `catalogue_productimage` (`id`, `original`, `caption`, `display_order`,
                                      `date_created`, `product_id`)
select id+4, original, caption, display_order, date_created, id+4
  from catalogue_productimage;
```

Фокус в том, что каждый последующий запрос создает в 2 раза больше записей, чем предыдущий, таким образом что бы дойти до значений около 1261 нам понадобится не более 11 таких запросов. Запросы отличаются друг от друга только прибавлением к ID очередной степени двойки. В последнем запросе нам надо будет ограничить максимальный id, запрос тогда получит условие `where id<=1261-1024`.

Comment: Спасибо, за расширенный ответ, супер!